# If existing record, row is returned, but if new record inserted, row is not returned

Tags: postgresql

Two tables. author, and book

I am adding a Book into the book table. 
If the Author is listed is already in the author table, then get the author's id and insert it into the Book row.
If the Author is not in the author table, then insert a new author and use the id to insert into the Book row.

This functionality works fine. 
The database responds appropriately and with the code below (not the actual code, but a more refined version) and rows are appropriately referenced or created.

I also want the query to return the Book row and this is fine. 
The Book row is always returned in all tested conditions, be it a Book with an existing author or a Book with a known author.

The issue comes when I now want to join it with the author table to get the author details back as well.

NOW -> 
If I insert a Book with a known Author, the functionality is perfect and the row is returned perfectly as expected.
If I insert a Book with a NEW Author, the new author is still created, the new book is still inserted BUT ZERO rows are returned.

I am not sure why this is happening or how I would go about getting the row.

```
CREATE TABLE author (id PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR (255));
CREATE TABLE book (id PRIMARY KEY, title VARCAR (255), author REFERENCES author (id));

WITH
s AS (
    SELECT id FROM author
    WHERE name = 'British Col'
),

i AS (
    INSERT INTO author(name)
    SELECT ('Eoin Colfer')
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from s)
    RETURNING id
),

j AS (
    SELECT id FROM s
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id FROM i
),

ins AS (
    INSERT INTO book
            (title, author)
    SELECT 'Artemis Fowl', j.id
    FROM j
    RETURNING *
)

SELECT ins.*, author.*
FROM ins
JOIN author
ON ins.author = author.id 
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Explanation

This has to do with the behavior of common table expressions in PostgreSQL.

Per the docs (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html):

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other
>   and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying
>   statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually
>   happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same
>   snapshot (see Chapter 13), so they cannot “see” one another's effects
>   on the target tables. This alleviates the effects of the
>   unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that
>   RETURNING data is the only way to communicate changes between
>   different WITH sub-statements and the main query. An example of this
>   is that in
>
> ```
> WITH t AS (
>     UPDATE products SET price = price * 1.05
>     RETURNING *
> )
> SELECT * FROM products;
> ```
>
> the outer SELECT would return the original prices before the action of
>   the UPDATE...

**The final sentence (below the code snippet) is critical.**

Your query against the author table at the end returns data as it was *before* the insert statements within the CTEs.

---

## Alternative Approach

An alternative approach would be to do this work in a function where you can use variables.

First, some suggested changes to your tables:

```
CREATE TABLE author
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE -- Unique for ON CONFLICT later
);

CREATE TABLE book
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT NOT NULL,
  author_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES author (id),
  UNIQUE (title, author_id) -- Prevent duplicates
);
```

Example function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_book (in_book_title TEXT, in_author_name TEXT)
RETURNS TABLE
  (
    author_id INT,
    book_id INT,
    author_name TEXT,
    book_title TEXT
  )
AS $$

#variable_conflict use_column

DECLARE
  var_author_id INT;
  var_book_id INT;

BEGIN

-- Upsert author, return id
INSERT INTO author (name)
VALUES (in_author_name)
ON CONFLICT (name) DO
  UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name -- Do update to allow use of returning
RETURNING id INTO var_author_id;

-- Upsert book, return id
INSERT INTO book (title, author_id)
VALUES (in_book_title, var_author_id)
ON CONFLICT (title, author_id) DO
  UPDATE SET title = EXCLUDED.title -- Do update to allow use of returning
RETURNING id INTO var_book_id;

-- Return the record using your join (similar)
RETURN QUERY
  SELECT a.id, b.id, a.name, b.title
  FROM author a
  INNER JOIN book b
  ON a.id = b.author_id
  WHERE b.id = var_book_id;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL VOLATILE;
```

Usage:

```
SELECT * FROM add_book('Artemis Fowl', 'Eoin Colfer');
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am trying to get away without creating postgres functions but it looks like this is something I will have to get to grips with.